# Does Vagrant Destroy also remove vagrant plugins?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have a number of test vagrant boxes on my system which I am tidying up. I installed  plugins eg like `vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater`and `vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers`. When I do `vagrant destroy` does that look get rid of the plugins while doing the destroy or not. I am deleting the directory after doing `vagrant destroy`so if not then how do I uninstall the plugins now that the directory has been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vagrant destroy` does not remove plugins. As per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/destroy.html, it "stops the running machine Vagrant is managing and destroys all resources that were created during the machine creation process".

You can uninstall plugins with `vagrant plugin uninstall <name>` (documented at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/plugin.html)

Comment: I am familiar with the uninstall command but I have deleted the directory that I installed the plugins into. Will the delete have uninstalled the plugins or are they installed into the registry or something ( I'm on windows). How can I uninstall these plugins since I now don't have the directory?

Comment: I'm not sure. Vagrant might maintain its own installed plugin manifest. Your original post sounded as though you're deleting the VM directory but your comment mentions you're deleting the actual plugin directory. To clarify, Vagrant plugins are installed at the Vagrant "level" and are not VM-specific. Are the plugins still listed in the output of ``vagrant plugin list``. If so, I'd try ``vagrant plugin uninstall <name>``. If it fails because it can't find the files due to you deleting that directory, you might need to install them again and subsequently remove them with the uninstall command.

Comment: Ok that explains a lot ... I assumed they were vm specific. I did a vagrant plugin list on a random folder and it showed up 2 plugins, and I managed to uninstall the triggers on ... this is unrelated but do you happen to know what vagrant-share is ... I don't remember installing that